# C++ size_t and ptrdiff_t for negative array indexing

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing, size-t, ptrdiff-t

I'm having difficulty choosing between `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` for the type of an index, which should need to be able to store a negative value.

To be precise, in my code I need to implement an array. I receive it's length (in the constructor) as a type of `size_t`, and when I overloaded the `[] operator` I need that the index would be of type `ptrdiff_t` (and not `size_t`), since I want to allow negative indexes, as this example shows:

```
std::size_t length = 50;
MyVector<int> vec(length);
vec[0] = 10;

MyVector<int> vec2 = vec+1;
std::cout << vec2[-1] << std::endl; //should print 10
```

The issue that arises from said design is that the range of avaiable indexes is limited by the maximum value of `ptrdiff_t`, and in some machines, **this upper limit is less than the maximum value of `size_t`**.

i.e. `std::numeric_limits<std::ptrdiff_t>::max() < std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()`

Thus, the problem is that the user might create an array with a size which is larger than the maximum value of `ptrdiff_t` (but still in range of `size_t`, of course), **but he wouldn't be able to access the array's elements which succeed over the maximum value of `ptrdiff_t`**, because their indexes would overflow to a negative number. On my machine, this cuts the avaiable indexes in half! (since both `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` are 64 bits, but one is `unsigned` and the other is `signed`)

Here are the solutions that I came up with, but sadly none of them are perfect:

1. In the constructor, accept a length of type `ptrdiff_t` instead of `size_t`, and add a check that verifies that the given length is not negative.

   **Pros:** It solves the issue, since now I would be able ot access all the elements in the array, and still allow for negative indexes.

   **Cons:** It limits the maximum possible length of the array. (e.g. like I said earlier, in my machine it cuts by half)
2. Leave things as they are, but in the `[] operator`, cast the index to type `size_t`, and make use of the fact that negative value would overflow.

   i.e. to the given index, add the difference between the element we're currently pointing to, and the

   for example, in my example before, since vec2 points to the *second* element in the arary, the `[] operator` would look something like

   ```
   template<class T>
   T& MyVector<T>::operator[] (std::ptrdiff_t index) {
       //Since vec2 points to the second element, we add 1.
       //For vec, we would add 0 since it points at the 
       //first element in the array.
       std::size_t actual_index = static_cast<std::size_t>(index + 1);

       //Do boundary checking

       return this->ptr[actual_index];
   }
   ```

   **Pros:** We're now able to access all the elements in the array.

   **Cons:** The usage becomes clumsy and ugly.
   For example, if we create a vector of size `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()`, then in order to access the last element, we need to access the '-1' element:

   ```
   MyVector<int> big_vector(std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max());
   big_vector[-1] = 5; // big_vector[-1] is the last element in the array.

   MyVector<int> big_vector2 = big_vector + 1;
   std::cout << big_vector2[-2] << std::endl; // would print 5, since big_vector2 points at the second element in the array
   ```

Comment: If you have 64 bit sizes anyway, then just go with solution #1. You can't even hope to have **9 exabytes** of operative memory, can you?

Comment: This would only be an issue for character types and on typical architectures integer wrapping would solve the problem "automagically" - if you take care with the expressions. In any event properly proofing `C++` code for potential integer overflow is a larger issue and involves a great deal of care and testing, so consider whether it really is a requirement for your application before putting too much effort into it.

Comment: You may have two overloads...

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant True, but I don't think the standard mentioned a lower limit for std::ptrdiff_t. So theoretically, there might be a machine where std::size_t is 64 bits long, but std::ptrdiff_t is only 16 bits, which is unacceptably low for an array size.

Comment: @Mikrosaft: While it is possible for `ptrdiff_t` to be smaller than `size_t` such architectures are exceedingly rare. Writing fully portable `C/C++` compatible with every odd-ball system possible is virtually impossible (e.g. requiring huge amounts of care, clumsy workarounds and nigh-impossible testing due to the rarity of unconventional platforms). The typical way to write `C++` code is to pick your battles and select a subset of the implementation-choices to be supported, then re-test/review later on if your guess should turn out to be wrong. Most code doesn't need to run on a 24-bit DSP.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having difficulty choosing between size_t and ptrdiff_t for the type of an index, which should need to be able to store a negative value.

Why have you limited yourself to size_t and ptrdiff_t? What about other integer types?

Do you have an actual plan to implement a container with 4.294.967.296 elements? (that is `2 ^ 32`).

I don't think there is a platform today that will assign that much memory - at least, not in consumer-level computers. Are you working on specialized hardware?

For generic-purpose C++, you can safely write a `std::size_t` - accepting constructor to a `std::ptrdiff_t` indexed class.

You will probably have to configure the accepted range of indexes, so that if you accept negative indexes, effective index range should be (-max32bit, max32bit).

This means, if you attempt to use the class with an index in the range (max32bit, max64bit), your class should throw an exception.

My solution would accept a `std::size_t` in the constructor (with clear documentation stating that the index ranges from -max(`ptrdiff_t`) to max(`ptrdiff_t`), and not from 0 to max(`std::size_t`). The class would then be indexed using a `std::ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: Are you sure that the initial length can be negative ?

Comment: The initial length cannot be negative. This is why I said the class should have a constructor accepting a `std::size_t` size.

Comment: 16 GB is not all that much

Comment: I just wanted to say that documentation should state that initial length should be in range **0** to max(ptrdiff_t)...